# Is this proof about the convergence of this integral right?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be an open bounded set and let $(u_n)_n\subset W_0^{1, p_1}(\Omega)$, $(v_n)_n\subset W_0^{1, p_2}(\Omega)$ with $p_1, p_2, >2$. Let $R>0$ be a constant. I want to show that this integral
\begin{align*}
\int_{\left\lbrace x\in\Omega\mid u_n(x)\leq R\right\rbrace} \left(\vert u_n\vert^{p_1 - 1} + \vert v_n\vert^{p_2 - 1}\right) \frac{\vert v_n\vert}{1 + \Vert v_n\Vert_{p_2}} dx
\end{align*}
is bounded. I would proceed in this way, could anyone tell me if it is right?
\begin{align*}
&\int_{\left\lbrace x\in\Omega\mid u_n(x)\leq R\right\rbrace} \left(\vert u_n\vert^{p_1 - 1} + \vert v_n\vert^{p_2 - 1}\right) \frac{\vert v_n\vert}{1 + \Vert v_n\Vert_{p_2}} dx\\
&\leq\frac{1}{1 +\Vert v_n\Vert_{p_2}}\left[\int_{\left\lbrace x\in\Omega\mid u_n(x)\leq R\right\rbrace} \vert u_n\vert^{p_1 - 1}\vert v_n\vert dx + \int_{\left\lbrace x\in\Omega\mid u_n(x)\leq R\right\rbrace} \vert v_n\vert^{p_2} dx\right]\\
&\leq \frac{1}{1 +\Vert v_n\Vert_{p_2}}\left(R^{p_1 -1} \Vert v_n\Vert_1 +\Vert v_n\Vert_{p_2}^{p_2}\right) \leq C \frac{\Vert v_n\Vert_{p_2}^{p_2}}{1 + \Vert v_n\Vert_{p_2}} < +\infty.
\end{align*}
Thank you for the help!

Comment: The first inequality is an equality, right? How do you justify that $\|v_n\|_{p_2}$ is bounded?

Comment: Right, the first inequality is an equality. Moreover $\Vert v_n\Vert_{p_2}$ is bounded because $(v_n)_n\subset W_0^{1, p_2}(\Omega)$, isn't it right?

Comment: Sorry. I meant $\|v_n\|_1$.